# modular arithmetic - proof not clear

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to understand a proof for a presentation and I am struggeling with 1 statement. I hope this problem is not too specific.
It is one of many propositions that is used for the derivation of fermat little theorem.
[The proof as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utV28.png)

My problem is the third line from below. In this line they want to show that there are two numbers in the same congruence class by choosing $s\geq 0$ and $0 < t < m - 1$ and they say $a^{s} ≡ a^{s+t}$.

I found a counterexample where this is not true:

Let's say $a = 3$ and $m = 7$, so a and m are coprime. Now we choose for $s = 0$ and let's see if $a^{s} ≡ a^{s+t}$. Then the left-hand side would be $3^{0} = 1$ and the right-hand side would have these values for all possible $t$: $3^{1}$,$3^{2}$,$3^{3}$,$3^{4}$,$3^{5}$. Taking these numbers mod 7 we obtain $3,2,6,4,5$ for the right-hand side. But the $1$ of the left-hand side is not congruent to any of these numbers on the right-hand-side. Maybe they made a mistake in the paper and they wrote $0 < t < m - 1$ instead of $0 < t \leq m - 1$. Or maybe I dont get the proof at all. Thanks for you help

Comment: Yes! You are right. It should be $0 <t \leq m-1$

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer