# Proof: If a and m are coprime, then $a^{t}$ ≡ 1 (mod m) for some t, 1 ≤ t < m.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a question regarding this proof:

If $a$ and $m$ are coprime, then $a^{t} ≡ 1 $ (mod m) for some t, $1 ≤ t < m$.
Since $a$ and $m$ are coprime, $m$ does not divide as for any $s$, and so the $m$ numbers
$1,a,a^{2}, . . . ,a^{m-1}$ all belong to the $m−1$ congruence classes other than the congruence
class of $[0]$.

So two of the numbers must be in the same congruence class: that is,
there exist numbers $s$ and $t$ with $s ≥ 0$ and $0 <t ≤ m−1$ so that $a^{s} ≡ a^{t+s}$  (mod m).
Now since $a$ and $m$ are coprime, we can cancel the common factor as from both
sides of the congruence to get $1 ≡ a^{t}$ (mod m).

I can not really justify this line: "$a^{s} ≡ a^{t+s}$  (mod m)"

My guess is that for $a^{t+s}$ I can obtain all possible residues, so $a^{t+s}$ gives residues in one "periode" and since $a^{t}$ does not reside in this periode but in another, $a^{s} ≡ a^{t+s}$ is gonna be true at some point. But for that I have to proof that if I take powers of $a:1,a,a^{2}, . . . ,a^{m-1}$, there is a repetition after a maximum of m-1 steps. And I am not sure how to show that, if that is even the reason behind the congruence "$a^{s} ≡ a^{t+s}$  (mod m)".

Thanks for your help

Comment: Didn't you just post this question the other day? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4173640/modular-arithmetic-proof-not-clear

Comment: You are right. Same proof but different question. Since the question was closed I do not know a good way to combine them.

Comment: By pigeonhole there are $\,s',s\,$ with $\,a^{\large s'}\!\equiv a^{\large s},\,$ wlog $\,s'>s.\,$ Let $\,t := s'-s\,$ so $\,s' = s+t.\,$ Then $\,t\ge 1\,$ by $\,s'>s\,$ and $\,t\le m-1\,$ since that's the maximum possible index difference  $\,s'-s\,$ (which occurs when $\,s' = m-1\,$ is largest, and $\,s = 0\,$ is smallest)

Comment: We applied pigeonhole to the map $\,f(k) := a^{k}\bmod m.\,$ It maps $\,m\,$ pigeons $\in\{0,1,\dots,m\!-\!1\}\,$ into $\,m-1\,$ holes = all $\rm\color{#0a0}{nonzero}$ residues or congruence classes $\!\bmod m,\,$ where $\,\color{#0a0}{f(k)\not\equiv 0},\,$ by $\,\gcd(a,m)=1\Rightarrow \gcd(\color{#c00}{a^k},m)=1,\,$ so $\,\color{#0a0}{m\nmid a^k},\,$ where we used that  coprimes  to $\,m\,$ (invertibles) are [closed under $\rm\color{#c00}{products}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/673192/242). $\ \ $

Comment: You can't combine them, but in the interests of transparency you can link them, that is, include in each a link to the other. Also, you can read the information given to you about why the other question was closed, and make improvements to get it reopened.

Answer (score 1):

It's essentially just using the pigeon hole principle, there are m "objects" that is our numbers

$1,a,a^2,...,a^{m-1}$

And they have to be "placed" in m-1 "boxes" that is the residue

$1,2,...,m-1$

So there will be at least two that are in the same "box" ie have the same residue

$a^t=a^{t+s} $(mod m)

And then canceling a^t gives us the result

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand this principle. But how I can be sure that the two objects that reside in the same class, does not reside in the right-hand side: $a^{t+s}$ (mod m). In other words. Let's say m = 7, then there are these possible residue classes: {1,2,3,4,5,6}. What if we have for any s the residue 1 on the left-hand-side, and for all t's we get following residue on the right-handside: {2,3,4,5,6} since 2 of the powers have the same residue of 2.

Comment: I think I can answer my own question. Since $1,a,a^{2},...,a^{m−1}$ share at least one class. We compare each a with all other powers. For example: m = 7 and $1,a,a^{2},...,a^{m−1}$ are {1,2,3,4,3,5,6}. Then we compare 1 with {2,3,4,3,5,6}, 2 with {1,3,4,3,5,6} and 3 with {1,2,4,3,5,6} and so on. And in this case for 3 we find the congruence.

Comment: I didn't understand what u mean by make sure that they don't reside on the rhs, because they are distinct, one will have larger exponent and one smaller, so assign t for the smaller a t+s for the larger and then it's done

Comment: Sorry I wrote $a^{t}≡a^{t+s}$ instead of $a^{s}≡a^{t+s}$. Maybe that is the reason we do not really understand each other. I edited it